# SSRS: Merge repeating cells in a COLUMN group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that includes an item hierarchy that goes across the report in columns.  I need to remove the duplicates that are occurring in the brand row as shown below:

```
     Brand 1      |      Brand 2      |
P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
i1 | i2 | i3 | i4 | i5 | i6 | i7 | i8 |
```

Instead what I'm getting is this:

```
B1 | B1 | B1 | B1 | B2 | B2 | B2 | B3 |
P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
i1 | i2 | i3 | i4 | i5 | i6 | i7 | i8 |
```

This is easy enough to do with *row* groups... But it seems a bit harder to do with *column* groups, which I am using in this case.

How can I get my Brand column group to appear like my top example?

Comment: The simple solution is to add another field to your *SQL* specifying Brand for each `Ps` value and then use column group based on `Brand,Ps` etc.

Comment: yes, thats what i have. however i cant seem to configure it in SSRS correctly not NOT repeat the brand for each P column. its like I just want the brand to "merge" for each brand group.  I can't seem to get it to do that. I don't think its a data problem honestly.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in my comment, I'm achieving the similar type of output for one of my report using column group.

e.g. to achieve following:

[image]

I got related value in the SQL result set and using column grouping like:

[image]

Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, this is what I had too. I figured it out. there is one critical step while configuring the report template in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is correct, there is one important step required. While adding a parent column group, you must select "Add group header" as shown:
[image]

You will still probably need delete a column (column only, don't delete your group!) after doing the above, but it will achieve what you want!